# Remote project with Zend Studio editor

Tags: zend-studio

I have just start using Zend Studio - 7.2.0 and i have some confusion.
I have attached one image where you can see working with remove server need a connection to that server, i have done it successfully but now when i download the remote project, it show two sub level 1. My Home and 2. Root ,
Can any one tell me what is the difference between theses two and what is there use.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That simply means that the home directory is the same directory as the lowest directory that the SFTP connection can go.  If your home directory was /home/user, My Home would go there and Root would go to /